# picklistsForRecordType in REST API

Tags: rest-api, page-layout, picklist, record-type

Version 29.0 of the REST API includes an attribute for `picklistsForRecordType` in the response to `/sobjects/<object>/describe/layouts`, but it appears to always be an empty array.  Is there a way to enable this feature, or is it simply a placeholder for a future API version?

We have been using the SOAP API's `describeLayout` call to retrieve page layouts along with `picklistsForRecordType` mappings.  Unfortunately, we have a customer org in which `describeLayout` returns a 20MB (uncompressed) XML document for `Account`, big enough to crash an iOS hybrid app using the Ajax Toolkit, so I'm eager to move to the REST API for page layouts and picklist option mappings.

Comment: Thats weird .I think best will be contact customer support and raise this

Answer (score 1):

This is now listed as a known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2GwAAK

Comment: The known issue has been marked as Won't Fix.  There's also an Idea to solve this problem: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5SnAAI

Answer (score 1):

As of API version 32.0, RecordTypes can be retrieved from the Tooling API, e.g. `/services/data/v32.0/tooling/sobjects/RecordType/<RecordTypeId>`.  The `Metadata` attribute contains an array of `picklistValues`, containing the `picklist` field and the `values` for the RecordType.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Tooling API does NOT return all packaged picklist fields and for customers/partners using the translation workbench, the picklist values do NOT come back as translated. Unfortunately these two issues make this solution unusable for us.